# Print indices of matching list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I can't figure out why this is printing `[0, 2, 3, 3]`. I need to print the index of each element in `lst1` that is equal the the corresponding element in `lst2`. so i should be getting `[0, 2, 3]`. I'm fairly new to python so i must not be grasping the order in which for loops iterate through a list or something.

```
def same_values(lst1, lst2):
  final = []
  for num in lst1:
    if lst2[lst1.index(num)] == num:
      final.append(lst1.index(num))
  return final
print(same_values([5, 1, -10, 3, 3], [5, 10, -10, 3, 5]))
```

Comment: Hint: What is `lst1.index(3)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occur because the code lst1.index(num) returns the value 3 twice once the elements index 3 and 4 are equal.

It is safer to use a different approach:

```
def same_values(lst1, lst2):
    final = []
    for i in range(len(lst1)):
        if lst1[i] == lst2[i]:
            final.append(i)
    return final
print(same_values([5, 1, -10, 3, 3], [5, 10, -10, 3, 5]))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`lst1.index(3)` will return `3` both times, because that's the **first occurrence** of `3` in `lst1`.

Instead, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over the lists in parallel, and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to access the index.

```
def same_values(lst1, lst2):
    final = []
    for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)):
        if v1 == v2:
            final.append(i)
    return final

print(same_values([5, 1, -10, 3, 3], [5, 10, -10, 3, 5]))  # -> [0, 2, 3]
```

Here the bit `for i, (v1, v2) in ...` uses a nested iterable unpacking.

Plus you can simplify that into a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), though it's a little noisy:

```
def same_values(lst1, lst2):
    return [i for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)) if v1 == v2]
```

Answer (score 0):

5, -10, 3, 3 are being matched because you're scanning the entire second list each time

Note: you can get the index and element using enumerate

```
for i, num in enumerate(lst1):
```

---

If you want to compare "corresponding indices", access both lists and compare rather than "find the index of a matching element" using `index(num)`

Also check out the `zip()` function